# Css Hover Transição

Tags: html, css

Amigos, tenho o seguinte code

https://codepen.io/narrador/pen/vWbrPr

No efeito atual quando eu passo o mouse o efeito hover muda o background e aumenta as proporções da div até ai beleza, porém eu gostaria que o efeito não mexesse com as outras divs, no efeito atual se eu passar o mouse sobre o primeiro elemento os outros da direita se movem.

Como arrumar isso? fazendo com que as outras divs não se movam quando eu der um hover nos outros elementos.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

@Patrique Alves,

Inicialmente seu CSS contém uma propriedade com erro logo no comecinho:

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing:
     }
```

...deve ficar assim:

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: 0;
     }
```

Seguindo, esse movimento se dá por conta da tag "li" estar com o valores diferentes; veja:

```
    .nav li{
        ...
        width: 145px;
        height: 150px;
        ...
    }

    .nav li:hover{
        ...
        width: 145px; /* Deve ficar igual ao ".nav li {...}" */
        height: 150px;  /* Deve ficar igual ao ".nav li {...}" */
        ...
    }
```

Com esse ajuste o movimento se restringirá a cada objeto.

**Para o efeito esperado** acredito ser o que está faltando no CSS ".nav li:hover". Mude o código conforme abaixo e teste. Comigo funcionou bem parecido com o que você precisa.

```
    .nav li:hover{
        opacity:1;
        /*width:155px;*/
        height:160px;
        background:rgba(11, 132, 138, 0.7);
        z-index: 2;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);   
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mais desta forma o efeito apenas troca o fundo, eu gostaria que ele aumentasse por isso coloquei maior, porém quando eu aumento ela se move, gostaria de saber como aumentar sem mover as outras

Comment: seria algo como isso https://codepen.io/wifeo/pen/qzwkb porém não estou conseguindo colocar

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir arrumar, agora está como eu gostaria.

https://codepen.io/narrador/pen/LOqJeY